# Angular2 RxJs Observables: filter vs map?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Both the  Filter and Map `rxjs` functions seem to be ways to manipulate a `rxjs Observable`'s stream. After tinking with them and from examples I've seen, they both seem to do the same thing.

What's the difference and when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 20):

- **Filter:** Removes emitted data from the stream.
- **Map:** Transforms it.

They do the exact same as the corresponding `Array` methods.

E.g.

```
const stream = Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5]);

stream
  .map(x => x * 2)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // 2,4,6,8,10

stream
  .filter(x => x > 3)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // 4,5
```

Maybe this site helps to understand the difference: https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: I also recommend this: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/. Reference for [`.map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) and [`.filter`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter).

Comment: What about `filter` in a `pipe`? i find filter doesn't unwrap the array, so i have to still filter inside the filter function: `filter(x => x` (x is an array)